# How to say waitForIdleSync() in annotated UIThreadTest method

Tags: java, android, testing, user-interface

In my test Project all methods doesn't have the annotation `UiThreadTest`, the advantage is that I can perform clicks and anything else and wait then with `getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();` for the UI. But the disadvantage is that a button in my ui opens a  dialog, which calls `getActivity()` in his constructor - this method returns null, because my test method has not the annotation `UIThreadTest`, when I add it then the dialog opens, but I can't use `waitForIdleSync`.

**So is there any equivalent code to wait for the ui with this annotation**?

Comment: Have you tried Robotium? I've used the various Solo methods to wait for dialog titles to show up, click buttons on dialogs, etc.: http://robotium.googlecode.com/svn/doc/com/robotium/solo/Solo.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience its good to limit your use of this annotation, what i tend to do is run any code that needs to interact with the Ui thread within a runnable the format is which:

```
getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //code that needs to run on UI thread
    }
});
```

you can then use the waitForIdleSync before and after any actions you do.

Comment: Thx for reply, I thin kyou are right, but the problem with this that I can't test dialogs in my code (because getActivity() returns null - I forget to mention that I use Fragments), is there any other way to do that without this annotation?

Comment: Do you mean putting a `waitForIdleSync()` after each `runOnMainSync()` or after each action within the `Runnable`?